# ProGuard with AppBundle and data-binding: IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-app-bundle

I have a multi-module project (I use Android App Bundles) with data-binding, ViewModel. But when I enable `Proguard` the app crashes with the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBindingUtil.setConte… R.layout.my_activity) must not be null

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBindingUtil.setConte… R.layout.my_activity) must not be null
        at MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.kt:38)
```

When I remove modules and create one `app` module, everything works. When I disable `Proguard`, it also works fine.
Here is part of my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class com.example.module1.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class com.example.module2.databinding.** { *; }
```

In `build.gradle`:

```
minifyEnabled true
useProguard true
```

So the error points to this line of code:

```
val binding: com.example.module1.databinding.MyActivityBinding =
                DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.my_activity)
```

Maybe any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only need to add this to your `proguard-rules.pro`, where module1 and module2 are Dynamic Feature Modules with databinding enabled.

```
-keep class com.example.module1.DataBinderMapperImpl { *; } 
-keep class com.example.module2.DataBinderMapperImpl { *; }
```

Comment: Three days ago I found out the same solution, so I just looked at usage.txt file from `/build/outputs/mapping directory` (it lists the code that was removed from the APK by obfuscating), and returned some classes from that file that I think may affect the error :) So accept the answer, it may be helpful for others!

Comment: can also be defined as `-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper { *; }`

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know why but for me, the following combination worked:

```
-dontwarn androidx.databinding.**
-keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper
```

I tried using just `-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper` but it didn't work.

Also I tried using

```
-dontwarn androidx.databinding.**
-keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }
```

but that didn't work either.

What worked was a **combination** of the three.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper { *; }`

Answer (score 0):

if you enable to view merged proguard file using

```
-printconfiguration proguard-merged-config.txt
```

You will see something like this is there to keep `DataBinderMapperImp`

```
 # instant apps load these via reflection so we need to keep them.
-keep public class * extends android.databinding.DataBinderMapper
```

I think what is missung is `androidx` version

I added this line it working fine now

```
-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper { *; }
```